# Need Sample Project in objective c Using AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I have tried searching, but have not had much luck finding a project that uses the AVPlayerViewController class. I am interested in adding custom buttons and changing the colour of the UI.

I can't use CocoaPods and my coding language is Objective C.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Introduction/Intro.html http://www.modejong.com/blog/post13_iOS8_SunSpot/index.html

Comment: Attempt to get this to make sense

Comment: @rleedev i have AVPlayerViewController custome class but you have to add buttons  and UI.